# ASP CORE Identity browser login fail but via UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync with literal string work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm use mvc core 3.1 with Identity  3.1.2, with default built-in UI:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

I wrote hard code that creates initial administrator user:

```
var userAdminExists = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");

if (userAdminExists == null)
{
    var user = new IdentityUser
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        UserName = "Admin",
        Email = "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
        EmailConfirmed = true
    };


    var x = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, _IConfiguration.GetValue<string>("defaultAdminPassword"));

    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "AdminRole");
}
```

(Of course I also tried to write the literal password inside the code, for those wondering about the IConfiguration, and I also watched the entries at break-points and everything worked as planned).

the user is created, but when i login with this email address and password in the browser i get "Invalid login attempt." (in normal response, status 200).
I wrote test code:

```
var pass = _configuration.GetValue<string>("defaultAdminPassword");
var res = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("xxxx@gmail.com"), pass);
```

And of course it return true...

furthermore, also if i reset password via email reset link ("Forgot your password?") and i set new password, is not work...

but new users created through the "Register" UI interface, work great.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Identity UI to sign in, you end up calling [`SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_PasswordSignInAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_):

> ```
> public virtual Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(
>     string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure);
> ```

As you can see from this signature, the first parameter is `userName`. When you use the UI as you've described, you provide the email address where the userName is expected. However, when you call `FindByEmailAsync` and pass the result into `CheckPasswordAsync`, you find the user based on `Email` and not `UserName`, which works.

When you register a new user using the Identity UI, you end up running [this code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Register.cshtml.cs#L135-L136):

> ```
> await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
> await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
> ```

As you can see, this sets both the `UserName` and the `Email` to `Input.Email`. This is why you are able to sign in with these accounts.

Answer (score 0):

> when i login with this email address and password in the browser i get "Invalid login attempt." (in normal response, status 200).

If `RequireConfirmedAccount` option is set to **true** while configuring Identity service as below, the registered user login with that account but not confirming the account, which would cause this issue.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

"*Invalid login attempt*" message

[image]

So please make sure the user confirm the account before user login app with that account. Besides, if account confirmation is not needed in your app, you can set `RequireConfirmedAccount` option is set to **false**.

```
options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
```

Comment: thank for your answer, i have set the `user.EmailConfirmed = true` and it does not help, and I also did what you suggested (see the edit of my question) and still does not work.

Comment: `have set the user.EmailConfirmed = true and it does not help` Please check if corresponding record of that account in **AspNetUsers** table with value **True** on **EmailConfirmed** column。

Comment: Yes its true, and I checked it out before I asked.